# I want to add two related columns and reduce the data matrix by half

Tags: r

```
DF <- data.frame(hour1=c(3,2,1), 
                 minutes1=c(0.083,0.17,0.25),
                 hour2=c(4,3,2), 
                 minutes2=c(0.09,0.18,0.35))

DF
#>   hour1 minutes1 hour2 minutes2
#> 1     3    0.083     4     0.09
#> 2     2    0.170     3     0.18
#> 3     1    0.250     2     0.35
```

What I am looking for must be more efficient because I have to add 58 pairs of columns....

```
DF_new<-DF%>%summarise(t1=hour1+minutes1,
                    t2=hour2+minutes2)
DF_new
#>      t1   t2
#> 1 3.083 4.09
#> 2 2.170 3.18
#> 3 1.250 2.35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pivot to long format, add the columns, then pivot back to wide. This works as expected with your example, but will work with an arbitrary number of columns

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)', 
               names_to = c(".value", "t")) %>%
  mutate(time = hour + minutes, t = paste0('t', t)) %>%
  select(t, time) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = t, values_from = time, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      t1    t2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  3.08  4.09
#> 2  2.17  3.18
#> 3  1.25  2.35
```

A simpler approach, provided you only have the hour and minutes columns in DF would be to select the hours columns and minutes columns then add them:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% 
  transmute(across(contains('min'), ~.x) + across(contains('hour'), ~.x)) %>%
  rename_with(~sub('minutes', 't', .x))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      t1    t2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  3.08  4.09
#> 2  2.17  3.18
#> 3  1.25  2.35
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

hour <- names(DF)[grep('hour', names(DF))]
min <- names(DF)[grep('min', names(DF))]

map2_dfc(hour, min, ~{
  col <- paste0('t', gsub('([a-z]+)(\\d$)','\\2', .x))
  DF %>% rowwise() %>% transmute(!!col := .data[[.x]] + .data[[.y]])
})
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
     t1    t2    t3    t4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  3.08  4.09  6.1   4.09
2  2.17  3.18  2.17  3.28
3  1.25  2.35  1.25  6.35
```